# Model Form is not saving data

Tags: python-3.x, django, web

model.py
'''

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    BMI = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    blood_sugar = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    HB = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    platelets = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.TextField()
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):
    return self.patient.name
```

'''

forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AppointmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['patient'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def appointment(request):
    docname = request.POST.get('docname')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('success')
    form = AppointmentForm(initial={"patient":request.user})
    form = AppointmentForm(initial={"doc_name": docname})
    return render(request, 'appointment.html', {'form': form})
```

When saving form it is redirected to "success" page (means form is valid) but data is not saved in database.

appointment.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>


</html>
```

I am new to django, I created a form to save Data into my database but its not working, I got no error but data is not sent in database.
I've tried every thing but cant find any problem.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Has the form reached inside the the block `if form.is_valid():` to actually `return redirect('success')`?

Comment: yes, but thanks i got it working now

Answer (score 0):

In your `form` `action="."` attribute makes the problem. to get rid of it make `action=""`, then it will pass all the values for the same view.